# Running a durandal app with the main-built file results does not work

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, weyland

I am having some problems with the optimized code that weyland generates. Here is what I did so far:

This is my project structure:

[image]

This is my weyland-config file:

```
exports.config = function(weyland) {
weyland.build('main')
    .task.uglifyjs({
        include:['www/**/*.js', 'www/js/durandal/**/*.js']
    })
    .task.rjs({
        include:['www/**/*.{js,html}', 'www/js/durandal/**/*.js'],
        loaderPluginExtensionMaps:{
            '.html':'text'
        },
        rjs:{
            name:'libs/require/require', //to deploy with require.js, use the build's name here instead
            baseUrl : '../www/js',
            paths : {
                'text': 'libs/require/text',
                'durandal': 'durandal',
                'plugins': 'durandal/plugins',
                'transitions': 'durandal/transitions',
                'knockout': 'empty:',
                'bootstrap': 'empty:',
                'jquery': 'empty:'
            },
            inlineText: true,
            optimize : 'none',
            pragmas: {
                build: true
            },
            stubModules : ['text'],
            keepBuildDir: true,
            out:'../www/js/main-built.js'
        }
    });
```

}

This is what I added in my index.html file to run the generated file instead of the one created by me:

```
<script src="js/main-built.js"></script>
```

I have also tryed using:

```
<script data-main="js/main-built" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

This is what I had before:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

After I run weyland build on the command line the main-built file get's generated without any errors.

If I try to run the app the applycation freezez at the start screen as if the the app.start() method never get's called and no errors are being displayed.

I have checked chrome debugging tools the main-built file is recieved by the client it just seems it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have also tryed building using almond-custom and ading this aditional configuration:

```
insertRequire:['main']
wrap:true
```

When I try to run the app I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: main missing durandal/app
```

In my main fail I am loading the 'durandal/app' threw require js and for some reason it can not find it anymore